# Synchronisation of HashMap used privately

Tags: java, hashmap, synchronization

I have a class extending ArrayList which keeps it's own private HashMap to be used only by the said class. Do I need to worry about synchronisation in that case?

Comment: only if publicly accessible methods interact with your map in a non-threadsafe manner (either directly or by proxy)

Comment: If 'privately' means 'by only one thread', no, otherwise yes.